# Parallel construction of a distance matrix

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, distance, hierarchical-clustering

I work on hierarchical agglomerative clustering on large amounts of multidimensional vectors, and I noticed that the biggest bottleneck is the construction of the distance matrix. A naive implementation for this task is the following (here in Python):

```
''' v = an array (N,d), where rows are the observations
and columns the dimensions'''
def create_dist_matrix(v):
   N = v.shape[0]
   D = np.zeros((N,N))
   for i in range(N):
      for j in range(i+1):
          D[i,j] = cosine(v[i,:],v[j,:]) # scipy.spatial.distance.cosine()
   return D
```

I was wondering which is the best way to add some parallelism to this routine. An easy way would be to break and assign the outer loop to a number of jobs, e.g. if you have 10 processors, create 10 different jobs for different ranges of `i` and then concatenate the results. However this "horizontal" solution doesn't seem quite right. Are there any other parallel algorithms (or existing libraries) for this task? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this what is done by `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(XA, XB, 'cosine')`

Comment: It is actually, but are those methods parallelized? I am currently using `pdist` but it takes too long.

Comment: Not parallelized, but probably much faster because you'd be doing more of the work in native C code rather than python.

Comment: Yes I know that. I am just looking for an even faster solution than `pdist`, which I am currently using. I provided the code to give an idea about the sequential form of the task, to help people suggest parallel versions.

Comment: Good question.  Vector comparisons are ideal for parallelization and there really should be a way to construct the matrix in a way that is both implementationally efficient and parallel.

Answer (score 21):

Looks like `scikit-learn` has a parallel version of pdist called [pairwise_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

D = pairwise_distances(X = v, metric = 'cosine', n_jobs = -1)
```

where `n_jobs = -1` specifies that all CPUs will be used.

Comment: Note that this calculates the *full* `N` by `N` distance matrix (where `N` is the number of observations), whereas `pdist` calculates the condensed distance matrix (a 1D array of length `((N**2)-N)/2`. You can of course convert from one type of distance matrix to the other, but there are memory usage considerations with `pairwise_distances` in that it generates a bunch of data that you may not need, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 4):

See @agartland answer — you can specify `n_jobs` in [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) or look for clustering algorithm at [sklearn.cluster](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster) with `n_jobs` parameter. E. g. `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`.

Still, if you feeling adventurous, you can implement your own computation. For example, if you need 1D distance matrix for `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from time import time as ts


data = np.zeros((100,10)) # YOUR data: np.array[n_samples x m_features]
n_processes = 4           # YOUR number of processors
def metric(a, b):         # YOUR dist function
    return np.sum(np.abs(a-b)) 


n = data.shape[0]
k_max = n * (n - 1) // 2  # maximum elements in 1D dist array
k_step = n ** 2 // 500    # ~500 bulks
dist = np.zeros(k_max)    # resulting 1D dist array


def proc(start):
    dist = []
    k1 = start
    k2 = min(start + k_step, k_max)
    for k in range(k1, k2):
        # get (i, j) for 2D distance matrix knowing (k) for 1D distance matrix
        i = int(n - 2 - int(np.sqrt(-8 * k + 4 * n * (n - 1) - 7) / 2.0 - 0.5))
        j = int(k + i + 1 - n * (n - 1) / 2 + (n - i) * ((n - i) - 1) / 2)
        # store distance
        a = data[i, :]
        b = data[j, :]
        d = metric(a, b)
        dist.append(d)
    return k1, k2, dist


ts_start = ts()
with Pool(n_processes) as pool:
    for k1, k2, res in pool.imap_unordered(proc, range(0, k_max, k_step)):
        dist[k1:k2] = res
        print("{:.0f} minutes, {:,}..{:,} out of {:,}".format(
            (ts() - ts_start)/60, k1, k2, k_max))


print("Elapsed %.0f minutes" % ((ts() - ts_start) / 60))
print("Saving...")
np.savez("dist.npz", dist=dist)
print("DONE")
```

Just so you know, `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` implementation isn't parallel and its complexity is at least O(N*N). I'm not sure if `scipy` has parallel implementation of this function.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will get it any faster than `pdist` in the `scipy` module. Probably this is why it says

> Note that you should avoid passing a reference to one of
>   the distance functions defined in this library. For example,:

```
dm = pdist(X, sokalsneath)
```

> would calculate the pair-wise distances between the vectors in
>   X using the Python function sokalsneath. This would result in
>   sokalsneath being called n choose 2 times, which
>   is inefficient. Instead, the optimized C version is more
>   efficient, and we call it using the following syntax.:
>
> ```
> dm = pdist(X, 'sokalsneath')
> ```
>
> So no Python function is used, if you use `pdist(X, 'cosine')`. When I run it, to me it seems, that it does only use one core, so if you have a lot of cores, you might get it faster. But bear in mind, that to achieve this, your native implementation has to be as fast as SciPy's. That won't be trivial. You'd rather be patient or go for a different clustering method, e. g. an algorithm which supports a spatial index.

Comment: but `pdist` in `scipy` is utilizing only 1 thread / process, which is slow

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @agartland proposed I like to use [`pairwise_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) or [`pairwise_disances_chunked`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked) with [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to get the condensed distance vector. This being the exact output provided by [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

It is important to note the `k` kwarg for `triu_indices` controls the offset for the diagonal. The default value `k=0` will return the diagonal of zeros as well as the real distance values and should be set to `k=1` to avoid this.

For large datasets I have encountered an issue where `pairwise_distances` raises a `ValueError` from `struct.unpack` when returning values from a worker thread. Thus my use of `pairwise_distances_chunked` below.

```
gen = pairwise_distances_chunked(X, method='cosine', n_jobs=-1)
Z = np.concatenate(list(gen), axis=0)
Z_cond = Z[np.triu_indices(Z.shape[0], k=1)
```

For me this is much faster than using `pdist` and scaled nicely with the number of available cores.

**N.B.** I think it is also worth pointing out that there was in the past some confusion about the arguments for `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` in that the documentation at one point indicated that users could pass a condensed or squareform distance vector/matrix ([linkage() function mistakes distance matrix as observation vectors #2614](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2614)). This is in fact not the case and the values passed to linkage should be either the condensed distance vector or the m x n array of raw observations.

Comment: This looks promising! Can we use reduce_func to return its output in a sparse format chunk by chunk?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to orchestrate the multiprocessing by yourself you may want to split the number of calculations evenly between CPUs so that to maximally shorten the calculations. Then replies to [this question on equally splitting the diagonal matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237201/how-to-split-diagonal-matrix-into-equal-number-of-items-each-along-one-of-axis/46240745#46240745) may come handy.