# Calculating euclidean distances with Python runs too slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra, euclidean-distance

I read to datasets from file into `numpy` arrays like this:

```
def read_data(filename):
   data = np.empty(shape=[0, 65], dtype=int)
   with open(filename) as f:
       for line in f:
           data = np.vstack((data, np.array(list(map(int, line.split(','))), dtype=int)))
   return data
```

I use `numpy` to calculate the euclidean distance between two lists:

```
def euclidean_distance(x, z):
   return np.linalg.norm(x-z)
```

After this, I calculate the euclidean distances like this:

```
for data in testing_data:
   for data2 in training_data:
       dist = euclidean_distance(data, data2)
```

My problem is that this code runs very slowly, it takes about ~10 minutes to finish. How can I improve this, what am I missing?
I have to use the distances in another algorith, so the speed is very important.

Comment: Use cdist - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html?

Comment: Of course, the complexity here is O(N*M) where `N` and `M` are the size of `testing_data` & `training_data` resp. So, it depends on how big both of these datasets are..

Comment: The testing dataset consists of 3823 and the training dataset 1797 data. So this means 6.869.931 distances have to be calculated, which I don't think it's that much that it has to take 10 minutes.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert Agreed, that's not much! One optimization could be to get rid of the manual creation of `list` and just use `np.fromiter(map(int, line.split(',')))`, although I think it might not give that much improvement. Another thing might be to get rid of the function `euclidean_distance()` and inline the code directly since it's just one line. It might give little boost since we're avoiding 6.8M function calls

Comment: @Divakar I have used `cdist` as well manual implementation using `numpy.linalg.norm` and didn't observe much difference in terms of speed.

Comment: Some strange thing happening here. I tried `cdist` and it runs in 2 seconds and if I improve my code as you said @kmario23 it takes the same time as before. I don't want to use `cdist` because that creates a matrix. How is this possible?

Comment: In which way you want to get the output if not a 2d numpy array?

Comment: This distance calculation is part of an algorithm the way I want to use is to give two lists of 64 length as parameters for my euclidean_distance function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) which allows you to allocate the work to all of your cores. [Parallel construction of a distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251148/parallel-construction-of-a-distance-matrix/55940399#55940399) discusses the same topic and provides a good discussion on the differences of `pdist`, `cdist`, and `pairwise_distances`

If I understand your example correctly, you want the distance between each sample in the training set and each sample in the testing set. To do that you could use:

```
dist = pairwise_distances(training_data, testing_data, n_jobs=-1)
```